# pdf arrives damaged on when I send it via email

Tags: vb.net

I want to send a pdf file via email, the file arrives but it damaged, any idea why?

```
Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(6499) {}
Dim bytesRead As Integer = 0         
bytesRead = file.FileByteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
Dim ms As New MemoryStream(bytesRead)
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(ms, "test.pdf", "application/pdf"))
mail.IsBodyHtml = False
mail.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("xxxxx@gmail.com")
mail.To.Add("yyyyyy@gmail.com")
mail.Subject = "test subject"
mail.Body = "test body"
mail.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.Normal
Dim smtp As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("mymail@gmail.com", "pass")
smtp.Port = 587
smtp.EnableSsl = True
smtp.Send(mail)enter code here
```

Comment: My guess is it has something to do with the process of reading the file into memory.  What is `file` as in `file.FileByteStream`?  I don't see where that is defined.

Comment: Why are you hard coding you're going to read 6499 bytes instead of looking at how many bytes are in the file? What if the file is much larger? Of course it will corrupt.

Comment: hi,file is a method that retrieves a string of bytes of a web service, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure from your question if you're reading the attachment in from the file system, but try changing this line:

```
Dim ms As New MemoryStream(bytesRead)
```

to this:

```
Dim ms = File.OpenRead("my file path")
```

and discard everything above it.

Comment: Hello, this file is not in any way